# DialogFragment и клавиатура

Tags: android, xml, dialogfragment

Как поместить `DialogFragment` **над** клавиатурой? При активации `EditText`, клавиатура закрывает часть диалога.

**`DialogFragment:`**

```
@Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        int style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, theme = 0;
        theme = R.style.BottomDialogTheme;
        setStyle(style, theme);
        Dialog alertDialog = new Dialog(getActivity(), R.style.BottomDialogTheme);
        alertDialog.setContentView(dialogView);
        //alertDialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
        return alertDialog;
    }
```

инициализация из другого фрагмента:

```
  private void onClickForget(View view) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_forget_password, null);
        BottomLayoutPopup bottomLayoutPopup = BottomLayoutPopup.newInstance();
        bottomLayoutPopup.setContentView(dialogView);
        bottomLayoutPopup.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), Consts.TAG_BOTTOM_POPUP);
        dialogView.findViewById(R.id.btnOk).setOnClickListener(v -> sendRecoveryRequest(bottomLayoutPopup));
        dialogView.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel).setOnClickListener(v -> sendForgetRequest(bottomLayoutPopup));
    }
```

**manifest:**

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

(пробовал `adjustResize` как  в манифесте, так и в `onCreateView` в диалог-фрагменте).

**layout диалога**:

**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="@dimen/dialogWidth"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_forget"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
            style="@style/DialogTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:text="@string/forgetPasswordLabel" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvMessage"
            style="@style/DialogMessage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:text="@string/tvMessageForgetName" />
        <TextView
            style="@style/ErrorStyle"
            android:id="@+id/tvErrorEmail"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:text="@string/errorEmail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/ltPasswordForgetHint"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textColor="@color/colorSpamText"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorSpamText"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/EditTextHint">
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etEmailForget"
                style="@style/EmailEditTextForget"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@null" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dialogRootBtnWidth"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
                style="@style/BtnDialog"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:text="@string/cancel"
                />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnOk"
                style="@style/BtnDialog"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:text="@string/dialogOkLabel" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**

Comment: Что-то я не понимаю, если клавиатура закрывает часть диалога, то диалог находится под клавиатурой. К чему тогда вопрос «Как поместить `DialogFragment` под клавиатуру?»?

Comment: @post_zeew опечатка, прошу прощения. Над клавиатурой* )

Comment: А `EditText` находится в `DialogFragment`?

Comment: @post_zeew да. Обновил вопрос, добавил layout диалог-фрагмента

Comment: А как Вы будете что-то набирать в `EditText`, если клавиатура будет за `DialogFragment`?

Comment: @post_zeew Клавиатура как раз закрывает определённую часть (кнопки, которые  ниже EditText. Т.е., ввести-то я могу, но после этого придётся закрывать клавиатуру и нажимать на нужную кнопку, что не удобно для юзеров.

Comment: Я это понимаю, но если Вы уберете клавиатуру за `DialogFragment`, то пользователь, чтобы что-то ввести в `EditText`, не сможет воспользоваться клавиатурой.

Comment: @post_zeew мне её нужно убрать под `DialogFragment`, а не за )

Comment: Типа нажимаем на `EditText`, клавиатура появляется, но чтобы ее увидеть нужно проскроллить `DialogFragment`?

Comment: @post_zeew нажимаем на `EditText`, клавиатура появляется прямо под диалогом, сразу же. (если реализовать обычный `AlertDialog` с `EditText`, то, собственно, так и будет. Но мне нужен `FragmentDialog`.
P.S. Диалог у меня занимает только определённую часть экрана. (в центре), поэтому тут без скролла